# regex conditional extract from last occurrence string till condition

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract the text : "Job Failed with error java.lang.Exception: input json must not be Empty !!!" from the below :

```
ABC failed!. Reason:Error. Reason: Job Failed with error java.lang.Exception: input json must not be Empty !!!  at com.fwk.commons.util.Parser$.validateStringInput(Parser.scala:56)  at ..
```

i.e., from the last occurrence of 'Reason:' till 2 spaces followed by 'at'.
If 2 spaces and 'at' is not found , I would like to extract until end of line.

This gives me everything after last occurrence of 'Reason:':  `.*Reason:(.*)`

Comment: What about: `.*Reason:(.*)(?<=!!!)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *lookahead assertion* to see if the string terminates with the given criteria. Following regex will extract everything after last `Reason` string to `at` preceded by two spaces, if   `at` is not found, it take upto the last character in the string.

```py
>>> re.findall('.*Reason:(.*?)(?=  at|$)', text)
 [' Job Failed with error java.lang.Exception: input json must not be Empty !!!']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can match the last occurrence of Reason and match  `at` after capturing the Reason, and make the match non greedy capturing at least a single char in group 1.

```
.*Reason:\s*(.+?)(?:\s+at\b|$)
```

- `.*Reason:` Match the last occurrence of `Reason:`
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `(.+?)` Capture group 1, match 1+ times any char non greedy
- `(?:\s+at\b|$)` Match 1+ whitespace chars and match `at` followed by a word boundary to prevent a partial match or assert the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h4EYz7/1)

```
import re
 
pattern = r".*Reason:\s*(.+?)(?:\s+at\b|$)"
s = "ABC failed!. Reason:Error. Reason: Job Failed with error java.lang.Exception: input json must not be Empty !!!  at com.fwk.commons.util.Parser$.validateStringInput(Parser.scala:56)  at .."
matches = re.search(pattern, s)
if matches:
    print(matches.group(1))
```

Output

```
Job Failed with error java.lang.Exception: input json must not be Empty !!!
```

Comment: Thank you @The fourth bird  . This works fine too but incase   at is not found, this returns nothing.

Comment: @pats4u in that case you can use an alternation `.*Reason:\s*(.+?)(?:\s+at\b|$)` https://regex101.com/r/h4EYz7/1

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use this pattern:

```
.*Reason:(.*)(?<=!!!)
```

[Regex-demo](https://regex101.com/r/yaqst2/1)